# How can I concat polars dataframes that have different columns

Tags: concatenation, append, python-polars

In pandas it happens automatically, just by calling `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])` and the frame that didn't have the column previously just gets a column filled with `NaN`s.

In polars I get a `'shape error'` with the message that the columns differ (11 cols in `df1` vs 12 cols in `df2`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Polars cares about schema correctness by default in operations and prefers throwing an error above silently succeeding as it might indicate a bug in your program.

If you want `polars` to add the columns, add the kwarg `how="diagonal"` to `pl.concat`.

```py
df_a = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [True, None, False],
})


df_b = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [4, 5],
    "c": ["bar", "ham"]
})


pl.concat([df_a, df_b], how="diagonal")
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b     ┆ c    │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ bool  ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ true  ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ null  ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ false ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ null  ┆ bar  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ null  ┆ ham  │
└─────┴───────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Damn i am blind. As soon as my eyes saw 'diagonal' in the documentation they skipped the paragraph immediately thinking it's something completely different. 

p.s. i love u (was starting to write spaghetti for loops with .lit() to get the job done)

Comment: I'm wondering why there are no similar keywords to the read_csv or read_parquet methods? As they do concatting under the hood if one specifies a mask...

Comment: @zacko yeah I knew diagonal existed but didn't consider it did what I want either. To be fair I'm not sure what I'd call it....